# MIPS: store address not aligned on word boundary when painting a bitmap

Tags: mips, cpu-word

I have this code:

```
.data
FP: .space 1048576 #firstposition of a 16x16 (w/h in pixels), 512x512 bitmap
colorred: .word 0x007f0000

.text

lw $s1, colorred
la $s2, FP

li $v0, 42
la $a1, 62
syscall
move $t0, $a0  #get a random integer and place it in t

li $v0, 42
la $a1, 62
syscall
move $t1, $a0

mul $t1, $t0, $t1
sw  $s1, FP($t1)

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

and I keep getting this error:
line 21: Runtime exception at 0x0040003c: store address not aligned on word boundary 0x1001020a

sometimes it does work and paints a bit in the bitmap but other times it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
sw  $s1, FP($t1)
```

Nothing in your code ensures that `$t1` is aligned on a word boundary. You need to clear the lower two bits of `$t1` before using it, like this:

```
li  $t2, 0xfffffffc
and $t1, $t1, $t2
sw  $s1, FP($t1)
```